# Chamilo LMS How to link to a test from a learning path?

Tags: chamilo-lms

In chamilo LMS, if you put a test in a learning path, it doesn't use the grade as passing, it uses completion as passing. So if you want the scores to count you have to tell users in a learning path, "Hey go find such and such a test in the exams section." I am trying to find a way to at least provide a link that will take the user directly to a specific test.

The chamilo forum is being hopeless spammed by a bot right now, so I cant get help there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why tests are graded by completion in learning paths is because learning paths are a teaching tool, by opposition to evaluation tool. As such, including tests there should only be used as a way to control whether you are good to move to the next chapter (using prerequisites) or not.
Teal exams should be taken apart for two reasons:

- to allow the student to prepare reasonnably (study on one side then, when (s)he's ready, enter the exam as if it was something formal
- to reduce possible interferences of JavaScript that is generated in the learning path context (you never know what other JS a teacher might add ti his/her tests)

In either case, you can still see the results of the tests from the user's tracking page (there's a column showing through which learning path it was graded, to make it clear).

You can use the URL of the test, then create a link to the test, then include the link in the learning path (this will open it as a content page but should track the results (not sure about that, you'll have to try it out) as if it was taken from out of a learning path.

Or you can also just put the link in an HTML document with a small explanation at the end of your learning path. This should send the user directly out of the learning path context and into the exercise context.